# How to find the domain of $(f^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(x)$, graph by hand, and evaluate using multiple functions

Tags: graphing-functions

If $f(x)=e^x$, $g(x)=|x+2|$, and $h(x)=\frac{x-2}{x+1}$, what is the domain of $(f^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(x)$?

I believe the answer to be $(-\infty,\infty)$ but I am not exactly sure of how to prove such an answer. $(f^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(x)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{e^{1/e^x}}$. For any value of x, the composite function is never undefined and thus has a domain of $(-\infty,\infty)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The second question is: Evaluate $((fg)/h)(3)$. Show all work necessary to reach your conclusion.

Based on my calculations, the answer is $20e^3$. Please correct me if I am incorrect.

The last question is graph $(g \circ f)(x)$.

I am unsure of how to do so by hand without a graphing calculator accurately. If possible please provide an explanation of how to do so.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $f^{-1}$ is intended to mean the inverse function of $f$, not the function $x\mapsto 1/f(x)$. So $(f^{-1}\circ f^{-1})(x)$ is $\log(\log x)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm could you show me the explanation for the first and second question?

Comment: I am not going to do your homework for you, no.

Comment: I am not saying to do my homework. Any hint would be appreciated. I mean to say if you could lead me to the correct pathway. By explanation, I am intending to indicate any assistance in solving this question.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $(g\circ f)(x) = |e^x + 2|$. You should use your understanding of domain and range to help you graph this.

First, the domain of this function is $(-\infty, \infty)$, since there are no restrictions on what values of $x$ we can put into $e^x$ or $|x|$. The range, however, is $[0, \infty)$ since the absolute value of anything has to be greater than or equal to 0.

Next, let's think about $g \circ f$ in terms of some elementary functions that you know. I assume you know what the function $e^x$ looks like. Then, $e^x + 2$ is a vertical shift of $e^x$ by 2 units. Finally, the absolute value will reflect any portion of the function that is negative about the $x$-axis.

Comment: Concerning evaluating ((fg)/h)(3), am I correct in my answer which I gave above?

Comment: Also, as for the domain of (f^-1 (composite)o f^-1)(x), am I correct in the answer i gave above and how would I prove the answer is correct?